# Read HttpResponseMessage in Ajax onSuccess

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

This is my APIController method -

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string url) {
    string responseString = GetWebApiData(url);

    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseString) && responseString.ToString().IsValid()) {
        response.ReasonPhrase = "Valid";
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    } else {
        response.ReasonPhrase = "Invalid";
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    }

    return response;
}
```

This is my ajax call to above method -

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:50/api/DC/" + formData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {


    },
    failure: function(response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

I am not able to read the HttpResponseMessage returned by the API Method. For both the conditions of OK and Bad Request, status code returned in 'xhr' of ajax method is '204' & 'No Content'. I need to validate based on response code. Any help pls!

I tried **success: function(response)** too, response was undefined.

Comment: Try removing `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: No luck by removing contentType

Answer (score 1):

The response is `204 No content` because you literally don't add any content. All you're doing is setting the response code. You can add content to the response like this:

```
response.Content = new StringContent("Return data goes here");
```

Alternatively use the `Request.CreateResponse()`/`CreateErrorResponse()` to create the `HttpResponseMessage` for you:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string url)
{
    string responseString = GetWebApiData(url);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseString) && responseString.ToString().IsValid())
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse("Valid"); // I'd suggest returning an object here to be serialised to JSON or XML
    }

    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid");
}
```

Comment: Is there any way i can read the response code? I can't use the Request.CreateResponse.... method as I have a WebAPI call within a WebApi so Request Object is null.

Comment: McCrosson I tried adding response.Content but the same was not sent to ajax success 'xhr'. Do I need to make any change to ajax call? I removed the contentType too. No luck..